# Cannot get Foreignkey Model and save it to Sqlite Database with Django

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I have looked over every article on everything that has ever been posted and none of the resolutions seem to fix my issues. I can't seem to get input from my view to save to my database. Theoretically the user will input a contact and business and the contact will associate with the business and the contact will be added however I am like 99% sure I am wrong somewhere, I am just 100% sure I don't know where:

Models

```
    from django.db import models


    class Business(models.Model):
       business_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
       date_created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

       def __str__(self):
           return self.business_name


    class Contact(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        number = models.CharField(max_length=13)
        email = models.EmailField()
        business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
             return "%s - %s" % (self.name, self.business)
```

Forms

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import Contact, Business



    class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['business'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Business.objects.filter(business_name=args[0]['business']))

        class Meta:
            model = Contact
            fields = ['name', 'title', 'number', 'email', 'business']


    class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Business
            fields = ['business_name']
```

Views

```
    def add_contact(request):
        all_contacts = Contact.objects.all
        if request.method == "POST":
            business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_name=request.POST['business'])
           form = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=business)
           print(form)
           if form.is_valid():
               new_form = form.save(commit=False)
               new_form.business = form.business
               form.save()
           else:
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contacts-homepage'))
           return HttpResponseRedirect('')
       else:
           return render(request, 'contacts/add.html', {'all': all_contacts})
```

Urls

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
         path("", views.contacts_home, name='contacts-homepage'),
         path("add/", views.add_contact, name='contact-add')

     ]
```

Add

```
    {% extends 'contacts/base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>FIS - AddContact</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {% block content %}

   <div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-3 border mh-100" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                   <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" style="border-color:black;border-style:solid">
                           <div class="container">
                                 <a class="navbar-text" href="" style="">Contact List </a>
                           </div>
                       </nav>
                   {% for all in all %}
                   <h3>{{ all.name }}</h3>
                   {% endfor %}
               </div>
               <div class="col-md">
                       <form action="" method="post">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                  <label for="name">Contact Name</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name"
                                         name="name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                  <label for="title">Contact Title</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title"
                                         name="title">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                  <label for="number">Contact Phone Number</label>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Phone Number"
                                         name="number" required>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                      <label for="email">Contact Email Address</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address"
                                             name="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                      <label for="business">Contact Business</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="business" placeholder="Business Name"
                                              name="business" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="position:relative;left:15px">Create Contact</button>
                           {% csrf_token %}
                        </form>
               </div>

            </div>
   </div>

    {% endblock content %}
```

While I assume this is trivial, I am still learning Django and Python in general so take it easy on me please.

Here is the error causing it to fail:

```
    <tr><th><label for="id_business">Business:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>“test” is not a valid value.</li></ul><select name="business" required id="id_business" multiple>
      <option value="1">test</option>

     </select></td></tr>
```

**Edit**

Form

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        business = Business.objects.filter(business_name=args[0]['business'])
    self.fields['business'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=business, empty_label=None, to_field_name="business_name")

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'title', 'number', 'email', 'business']
```

View

```
def add_contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_name=request.POST['business'])
        form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, instance=business)
        if form.is_valid():                
            form.save()
            print('valid')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contacts-homepage'))
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        all_contacts = Contact.objects.all
        return render(request, 'contacts/add.html', {'all': all_contacts})
```

**EDIT #2**

```
    def add_contact(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_name=request.POST['business'])
            form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, instance=business)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_form = form.save(commit=False)
                form.fields['business'] = new_form
                # print(form.fields['business'])
                form.save()
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contacts-homepage'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
        else:
             all_contacts = Contact.objects.all()
             return render(request, 'contacts/add.html', {'all': all_contacts})
```

I am getting closer, but its still not saving. It is running to form.valid(). The form.save(commit=False) is a business model type and is even correct in what model is returned but even if i set that directly as form.fields['business'] before I save it accepts but it never gets represented in the database and I dont get any errors to confirm whats going on. I am at a loss. Maybe its my PC.

**Edit #3**

I finally figured it out.

View

```
    def add_contact(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_name=request.POST['business'])
            form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, instance=business)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_contact = Contact(name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                              title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
                              number=form.cleaned_data['number'],
                              email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
                              business=business
                )
                new_contact.save()
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contacts-homepage'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
        else:
            all_contacts = Contact.objects.all()
            return render(request, 'contacts/add.html', {'all': all_contacts})
```

Comment: It is done, thanks

Comment: sorry. can you please update the full error trace

Comment: It seems like the issue arises when you pass test as the argument to a int id field. can you try passing in primary_key = True in the business field and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks. I have gotten it to finally validate but my form is returning as a Business model instead of a Contact model now so i can see it trying to save but its saving the wrong model now